# É recomendável criar uma splash screen customizada no phonegap?

Tags: apache-cordova, ionic

É uma boa prática criar uma `splash screen` customizada.

Por exemplo, existe o plugin de splash screen, mas eu gostaria de criar uma página própria, sem usar o plugin e gostaria de saber se isso é uma boa prática e se isso pode dar algum problema relativo a arquitetura do `phonegap/ionic`

Comment: Olá. Removi a tag [tag:ux] porque a sua pergunta não parece ter nenhuma relação com a experiência do usuário. Ela parece apenas relacionada às questões técnicas do phonegap e/ou ionic. Ok?

Comment: Não vejo nenhum problema em customizar uma splash.